# Prove Petersen graph is not Hamiltonian using deduction and no fancy theorems

Tags: graph-theory

Prove Petersen graph is not Hamiltonian using basic terminology and deductions. I'm looking for an explanation without k-colouring or anything fancy like that since I haven't covered that in class. Thanks!

Comment: Just try "all" possibilities systematically. Take some advantage of symmetry to cut down on the work.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221742/show-that-the-petersen-graph-does-not-have-a-hamilton-circuit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found at [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PetersenGraph.html):

The following elegant proof due to D. West demonstrates that the Petersen graph is non-Hamiltonian. If there is a $10-$cycle $C$, then the graph consists of $C$ plus five chords. If each chord joins vertices opposite on $C$, then there is a $4-$cycle. Hence some chord $e$ joins vertices at distance $4$ along $C$. Now no chord incident to a vertex opposite an endpoint of $e$ on $C$ can be added without creating a cycle with at most four vertices. Therefore, the Petersen graph is non-Hamiltonian.

There is a different simple proof [here](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/comb/ch11s.pdf).

Comment: I never covered chords in class.

Comment: In this context, a "chord" is just an edge joining two (non-adjacent) points on the cycle $C$. Think what a chord looks like in a circle in ordinary plane geometry, you'll get the picture.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a proof I like. The Petersen graph has $10$ vertices. If you have a Hamilton Cycle, it must go through each vertex. So then you draw this Hamilton cycle (just your basic cycle with $10$ vertices and $10$ edges). Now, Petersen graph has $15$ edges, so you have to add $5$ more edges to your cycle. However, any way you do this must create a $3$ or $4$ cycle, of which the graph has none. You can verify this last part for yourself and it is a simple combinatorial argument.

This type of proof is often quite effective for showing the lack of a Hamilton cycle.

Comment: Not to be rude, but unless I'm missing a point, I'm wondering - how does this have more upvotes than Gerry Myerson's answer which is another wording of the exact same argument and was posted a year prior to this answer?

Comment: @Sora. This answer is more readable for a beginner because it spells out what is going on more explicitly in contrast to Gerry's answer. The latter is perfectly fine for people who are more familiar with graph theory proofs.