# Which vertex removing create a hamilton circuit from Petersen graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonicity

> Show that the **Petersen graph**, shown here, does not have
>   a Hamilton circuit, but that the subgraph obtained by
>   deleting a vertex $v$, and all edges incident with $v$, does
>   have a Hamilton circuit. 
>   [image: Petersen]

**My attempt**:
I note that Ore's theorem${}^1$ is not satisfied. But this doesn't necessarily mean that no hamilton circuit exists. $\color{red}{\text{Is there any necessary condition which make it done}?}$ For the second part I think any inner or outer vertex removing done the Job because the original graph is **symmetric**. But is there any general way of thinking to removing a vertex from an arbitrary graph to come up with a Hamilton circuit.

---

Here is my main question: $\color{red}{\text{If the main graph isn't symmetric then how to know which vertex removing done the Job}?}$
$\color{red}{\text{Or any clues}?}$

> ${}^1$Ore states that: If $d(u) + d(v) \geq n$ for every pair of distinct nonadjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ of $G$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Comment: The Petersen graph is vertex-transitive, meaning $P-v$ is isomorphic to $P-v'$ for any two vertices, so you shouldn't have any difficulty coming up with a successful Hamilton circuit when you remove a vertex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove Petersen graph is not Hamiltonian using deduction and no fancy theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293364/prove-petersen-graph-is-not-hamiltonian-using-deduction-and-no-fancy-theorems)

Comment: Yes I haven't any difficulty coming up with a successful Hamilton circuit. But through this question I was wondering if a general graph which isn't vertex-transitive then how to come up with that particular vertex. And I think my question wasn't duplicate with your attached question because I ask different thing as well as a general question @MatthewDaly Sir

Comment: @MatthewDaly I think the OP wanted to know is there any general way of thinking to removing a vertex from an arbitrary graph to come up with a Hamilton circuit. Is that your want @Dr.Antidode$?$

Comment: @emonhossain Yes. That's my expectation. Thanks to clear it